# PyPi alternative for c++

Tags: c++, header, libraries, pypi

I'm searching for an alternative/similar to Pypi for C++ libraries/header files. Anyone an Idea where to find?

just found this one (http://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/links/libs) but in my opinion there must be pretty much more available

I'm most interested in matrix calculations

Thanks for your help

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Please read the rules.

Comment: You can also go through - https://github.com/rigtorp/awesome-modern-cpp

Comment: @badola thank you - that's nearly that what I searched for